# dotnet test runsettings passing testrun parameters with multiple values at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, .net-core

I need to pass multiple values like browser type, headless mode, device name at runtime via command line.

Attached the run settings file below. In command line, I need to modify these browser values, headless mode and device name at run time

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<RunSettings>
  <!-- configuration elements -->
 <TestRunParameters>
    <Parameter name="Browser" value="Chrome" />
    <Parameter name="Headless" value="True" />
    <Parameter name="Mobile" value=iPhone 6" />
</TestRunParameters>
</RunSettings>
```

dotnet test --filter TestCategory=Components Traffk.eApp.Web.Tests.csproj -s config.runsettings -- TestRunParameters.Parameter(name=\"Browser\",\ value=\"Chrome\")

How to pass the other values here in the above command.

Comment: Presumably by repeating the `config.runsettings -- TestRunParameters.Parameter(name=\"name\",\ value=\"value\")` portion